# plpgsql function creates sequences for row based tenancy?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Trying to create a function that looks for sequence with particular name if does not exist should create it.  Then returns function value of sequence.  Part of function that does not seem to be working is where it tests if sequence already exists. Below is code for function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."tenantSequence"(
    vtenantid integer,
    vtablename character)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$DECLARE 
  vSeqName character varying;
  vSQL character varying;   
BEGIN   
  select ('t' || trim(to_char(vtenantid,'0000')) || vtablename) INTO vSeqName;
  if not exists(SELECT 0 FROM pg_class where relkind = 'S' and relname = vSeqName )
  then 
    vSQL := 'create sequence '||vSeqName||';';
    execute vSQL;
  ELSE
    return 0;
  end if;
  return nextval(vSeqName) * 10000 + vtenantid;
END$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public."tenantSequence"(integer, character)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: UPPER vs. lower case? Btw: you don't need a select to assign a value to a variable. The first select can be simplified to: `vSeqName := 't' || trim(to_char(vtenantid,'0000')) || vtablename;`

Comment: Will change select statement.  What do you mean by UPPER vs lower case?? Will it work if keywords are in UPPERCASE

Comment: Given the fact that you are creating the function with camelCase, maybe your sequences are created like that as well. If you pass `foobar` as the tablename, but the sequence is created as `t0001fooBar`  then your function will not find it

Comment: Ok thanks for info will have a look tomorrow see if that's problem if so just convert string vseqname to lowercase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was case as mentioned by a_horse_with_no_name

changed line assign vSeqName to the following

```
vSeqName :=  lower('t' || trim(to_char(vtenantid,'0000')) || vtablename);
```

Now function works as expected.